# how does compiler/linker resolves kernel API like 'printk' called from a module on linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel, kernel-module

I have written a sample hello.ko kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>      /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>      /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world.\n");
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Here, I have used "printk" method which is a Kernel API exposed by Linux. I can see the Linux exported symbols in "/proc/kallsyms". I am curious to know how do gcc/ld links the called Kernel APIs? Does gcc/ld gets address of kernel method from "/proc/kallsyms" or some other file and perform linking? If yes, how do gcc/ld get to know that? I could not any option which tells that.

Comment: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4.2/kernel/module.c#L1197

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Linux kernel's module loader basically contains a special-purpose runtime linker. The .ko file is really an object file like any other, and as such it comes with a symbol table. If you run `nm` on it (`nm <path/to/some_module.ko>`), you'll see a lot of symbols marked "U", that is, "undefined". This includes symbols for core kernel functions that are used by the module, such as `printk`, `__kmalloc`, `kfree`, etc. but in many cases also symbols implemented by other modules.

When the module is loaded, the kernel runs through the module's undefined symbols and looks them up in the (run-time) symbol table, patching the relevant memory locations, much like any other linker. If any undefined symbols aren't already in the symbol table, loading will fail (easy to demo by using `insmod` instead of `modprobe` as it won't load dependencies). It also adds any symbols exported by the module to the symbol table for other modules to use, tracking dependencies so you can't yank out a module used by another. [Ilya Matveychikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651394) has linked to the relevant code in the module loader in the comments, which will help if you want to know all the gory details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was lazy for me to do it :)