# Which header file do I have to include to get printk() within a kernel source file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

Let's say I want to use `printk()` within `arch/x86/boot/string.c` before compiling the kernel. Which header file do I have to include so that the linker knows where to find `printk()`? I tried `#include <linux/kernel.h>` and `#include <linux/printk.h>` but I always get errors during `make bzImage` telling me the linker does not find `printk`:

```
arch/x86/boot/compressed/string.o: In function `memcmp`:
string.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `printk`
```

Comment: This might help: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/printk.h

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried to include `#include <linux/printk.h>` but the error still occurs.

Comment: It's not about headers. Something is wrong with linkage. Try `make clean` first.

Comment: Read ***[this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10946081/645128)*** on similar topic...  It does seem to point to a link problem

Comment: Tried `make clean`, didn't help. I'll have a read through the discussion.

Comment: Discussion was interesting but didn't help with my issue, there it's more or less a run time issue.

Comment: You are not telling the linker where to find the code for function printk.

Comment: Header files have nothing to do with linking. You need to know what library it is in and tell the linker to link with that library (like adding the switch "-lSomeLibrary.a" )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to instrument the boot stage of the kernel. It has its own really small library and doesn't have any headers like `linux/printk.h` available. The function is called `printf()` and it's implemented in *arch/x86/boot/printf.c*.

The output of this function goes to the channel whatever defined in BIOS (**int 10h**) and, if asked, to the legacy (you can't use UART which has 32-bit I/O, for example) serial line. For the details refer to the *printf.c* source file.

Comment: Ok, I see. Does `printf()` print to screen?

Comment: Do you know the equivalent for ARM architectures? There is at least no such file. Maybe one could use `putstr()` in `/arch/arm/boot/compressed/misc.c`.